# locate an a element and click on it in selenium pyhton

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this page and I want to click on the a element that sends an email(the one that is highlighted in the screenshot below [image]

and I have tried to find this element using By.XPATH
`email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'email-old-32')]").click()`

and By.CLASS_NAME

`email = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'email-old-32').click()`

and in both situations i'm getting an error no such element, does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible thing that may cause this:

1. You need to wait for element to be loaded and to become clickable. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` can be used for that.
   If this is your case instead of `email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'email-old-32')]").click()` try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'email-old-32')]"))).click()
```

2. The element class attribute value can be dynamic. Make sure it is not changing. In case it does - you need to find another, stable locator for that element.
3. The element can be inside `iframe`. In this case you will need to switch into the `iframe`.
4. Possibly you opened a new tab where the goal element is presented but forget to switch to a new tab.

Comment: it was opening in a new tab without switching the focus, got it fixed by running ```driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])``` to switch focus to the second tab. Thank you for drawing my attention towards that